# How to open list of my posts in google plus filtered by people group I posted for

Tags: google-plus

I logged in google plus, just added post. And I want to see what I posted earlier filtered by people group I posted for. I can open all my posts: `Home -> profile -> posts`. But how to filter these results by people group I posted for?

Answer (score 1):

You can then choose to "View profile as" and choose the group you're interested in.

You'll get public posts as well so this might not be as refined as you'd like but I can't see a better way of doing it.